# How to link to a symbol of a standard library in Dart doc comment?

Tags: dart

I'd like to insert a link to the class `Stream` of `dart:async` in my doc comment of my Dart library:

```
/// Link to [Stream].
library my_lib;

import 'dart:async' show Stream;

export 'src/my_lib_base.dart';
```

If I generate and serve my doc comments with `dartdocgen --include-sdk --serve .`, the word `Stream` links to http://localhost:8080/#my_lib/my_lib.Stream, which is not a link to class `Stream` of `dart:async`. It shows the same page as http://localhost:8080/#my_lib/my_lib. How can I link to the doc comment page of class `Stream` of `dart:async` instead?

Answer (score 1):

If `Stream` is in scope it should properly link to it. I think this is a bug, but `dartdocgen` seems to be deprecated. Use https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc instead.

Comment: I use the current dev version `1.12.0-dev.4.0`. If I run `dartdoc` I get many errors: `Caused by The null object does not have a getter 'importsAndExports'. NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'importsAndExports'`

Comment: I didn't use it myself yet. You might create a bug report in the GitHub repo.

Comment: If I use a stable release, `dartdoc` runs successfully. However, it doesn't create any link for `Stream`. Seems to be another bug ;-)

Comment: Weird. This is a very basic feature.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/739) for `dartdoc`.